# Как правильно задать ширину div при ресайзе экрана?

Tags: css

Есть вот такой код:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/martynuk/Lxj23u8j/)

```css
.html,
.body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.block1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
.block2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
.block3 {
  width: 85%;
  float: right;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
td {
  width: 10%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="block1">
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
      <li>five</li>
      <li>six</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
  <div class="block3">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>15</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

вся проблема в том что: синий блок не растягивается на всю высоту экрана, а блок с таблицей при ресайзе падает вниз, а должен сжиматься. Как правильно сделать, и вообще это возможно? перепробовал сотню вариантов, помогите плз?

Comment: вот часть ответа:синий блок теперь растянут на всю ширину экрана: `.block1{
    position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
}  .block2{
    margin-left:100px;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
#main {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
}
#side {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 150px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: table-cell;
}
#side-stuff {
  display: block;
}
#content {
  display: table-cell;
}
#content-stuff {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
.block2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
td {
  width: 10%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="main">
    <div id="side">
      <div id="side-stuff">
        <ul>
          <li>one</li>
          <li>two</li>
          <li>three</li>
          <li>four</li>
          <li>five</li>
          <li>six</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="content-stuff">
        <div class="block2"></div>
        <div class="block3">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>6</td>
              <td>7</td>
              <td>8</td>
              <td>9</td>
              <td>10</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>11</td>
              <td>12</td>
              <td>13</td>
              <td>14</td>
              <td>15</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Смотреть на **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a26yLn79/)**